# Magento Paypal Payflow Link always declines payment

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

Running Magento 1.8.0.0

When a user checks out with Paypal PayFlow Link it returns a popup saying:

**Payment has been declined. Please try again.**

Looking at the Paypal debug log, it reports that the credit card was authorized.

So I went looking at the controller:
**app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/PayflowController.php**

I can see from the code below that the allowed order state is false and thus it cancels the order.

```
    /**
 * When a customer return to website from payflow gateway.
 */
public function returnUrlAction()
{
    $redirectBlock = $this->_getIframeBlock()
        ->setTemplate('paypal/payflowlink/redirect.phtml');

    $session = $this->_getCheckout();
    if ($session->getLastRealOrderId()) {
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($session->getLastRealOrderId());

        if ($order && $order->getIncrementId() == $session->getLastRealOrderId()) {
            $allowedOrderStates = array(
                Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING,
                Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE
            );
            if (in_array($order->getState(), $allowedOrderStates)) {
                $session->unsLastRealOrderId();
                $redirectBlock->setGotoSuccessPage(true);
            } else {
                $gotoSection = $this->_cancelPayment(strval($this->getRequest()->getParam('RESPMSG')));
                $redirectBlock->setGotoSection($gotoSection);
                $redirectBlock->setErrorMsg($this->__('Payment has been declined. Please try again.'));
            }
        }
    }

    $this->getResponse()->setBody($redirectBlock->toHtml());
}
```

The returned order status is: **pending_payment**

I need help figuring out what is setting the order status incorrectly.

Comment: I'm on Magento 1.14, happens for me too, exact same thing.